# PHP list the date of each day, starting today's date, ending with the 15th day of next month

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out a way of coding this without having to hard code the number of days to write some PHP code to list the date of each day, starting with today's date and ending with the 15th day of next month (in the format: Thursday 1st January 2015).

This was my solution but as you can see I have hard coded the number of days

```
    //days until 15th for example
    $day = "25";

    $date = date("l jS  F Y");

    for($i=0; $i < $day; $i++ )
    {
      echo date("l jS  F Y", strtotime($date. ' + '.$i.' days'));
      echo "<br/>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a while loop that compares the date against 15th next month and counts up one day each iteration.

```
$date = date("l jS  F Y");
$end = strtotime(date("Y-m-15"). "+1 month");
echo $date . " <br/> \n";
While(strtotime($date)<$end)
{
  $date = date("l jS  F Y", strtotime($date. ' +1 days'));
  echo $date . " <br/> \n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/G38Xc

---

Another method is to use range and let it build an array with all the dates in Unix time then foreach it to echo the values.

```
$range = range(time(), strtotime(date("Y-m-15"). "+1 month"), (3600*24));

Foreach($range as $val){
    echo date("l jS  F Y", $val) . "\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/dj0nD

Using strtotime is quite significantly faster.
So unless you have reason to believe it's 2038 tomorrow then there is no reason to use datetime in my opinion.

https://3v4l.org/3CMQL

```
range method 0.17499923706055
datetime 4.0550231933594
```

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to use a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php) object:

https://3v4l.org/5WWev

```
<?php

// 15th 
$countUntilDay = 15;
$currentDate = new DateTime();
$date = clone $currentDate;
while(true) {
    echo $date->format('l jS F Y') . "\n";

    if((int)$date->format('d') === $countUntilDay && (int)$date->format('n') === (int)$currentDate->format('n') + 1) {
        break;
    }

    $date->modify('+1 day');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding 1 month in the fixed formatted date `strtotime(date("Y-m-15")` it will give you the `15th` day of the month. Then you can add a month in it by `"+1 month"` then compare and print the day normally.

```
$curDate = date("l jS  F Y");
$ending = strtotime(date("Y-m-15"). "+1 month");
echo $curDate . " <br/> \n";
While(strtotime($curDate) < $ending){
  $date = date("l jS  F Y", strtotime($curDate. ' +1 days'));
  echo $curDate . " <br/> \n";
}
```